# scala count number of nodes in a tree

Tags: scala, tree

I have a tree defined as

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

I would like a function to count the number of nodes in the tree and a function that counts the number of leafs

(I wrote a function to counts the number of leafs but I am not satisfied of the method that I am using. I would like a more "functional" implementation of that one).

```
val t1 = Branch(
             Branch(
               Leaf(12),
               Branch(
                 Leaf(3),
                 Leaf(4))),
             Leaf(8))                             //> t1  : trees.Branch[Int] = Branch(Branch(Leaf(12),Branch(Leaf(3),Leaf(4))),Le
                                                  //| af(8))

def n_nodes(t:Tree[Int]):Int = {
    var s = 0
    def n_nodesAcc(t:Tree[Int]):Unit = {

    t match {
        case Branch(left, right) =>{
            n_nodesAcc(left)
            n_nodesAcc(right )
            }
        case Leaf(v) => {s = s+ 1}
    }


}

n_nodesAcc(t)
s
}                                                 //> n_nodes: (t: trees.Tree[Int])Int

n_nodes(t1)                                       //> res0: Int = 4
```

(this is an exercise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might write a recursive method to count the leaves:

```
def countLeaves[A](tree: Tree[A]): Int = tree match {
    case l:Leaf[A] => 1
    case b:Branch[A] => countLeaves(b.left) + countLeaves(b.right)
}
```

Or count all the nodes:

```
def countNodes[A](tree: Tree[A]): Int = tree match {
    case l:Leaf[A] => 1
    case b:Branch[A] => 1 + countLeaves(b.left) + countLeaves(b.right)
}
```

You could also write a similar method to just get all the leaves, and you could have more flexibility to do different functions later:

```
def getLeaves[A](tree: Tree[A]): Seq[Leaf[A]] = tree match {
    case l:Leaf[A] => Seq(l)
    case b:Branch[A] => getLeaves(b.left) ++ getLeaves(b.right)
}
```

And then count with `getLeaves(t1).length`.  Or, similarly, get all the nodes:

```
def getNodes[A](tree: Tree[A]): Seq[Tree[A]] = tree match {
    case l:Leaf[A] => Seq(l)
    case b:Branch[A] => Seq(b) ++ getNodes(b.left) ++ getNodes(b.right)
}
```